# Docker run requires at least 1 argument error

Tags: docker, dockerfile, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy an image to DigitalOcean via GitHub packages.

I have logged in to GitHub and connected to DigitalOcean.

Now when I try to run my image like:

```sh
docker run -it -p 80:80 --name docker.pkg.github.com/myUser/appname/imagename:tag
```

I'm getting :

> Docker run requires at least 1 argument error

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try running without `-it`.

Comment: Same result as before

Comment: The `--name` is for setting the container name, not the image name. Docker is complaining that you did not pass an image name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright.

Typicall to find the answer after posting the question but any how.

I did these steps:

1. logged in to the github packages
2. connected to digital ocean
3. tried to push my images from github packages.

Problem was the order above. What i should have done:

1. connect to digital ocean
2. login to gihub registry
3. push image from github registry

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the **--name** value!

```sh
docker run --name mycontainer image:tag
```

Comment: The name prop is there. I tried your approach with just the name but the result is the same

Comment: @ThunD3eR This does not make sense. Run this: `docker run image:tag` and check that you should not have any error.

Comment: Then I get "unable to find image locally". but when i run docker ls images I can see it there

Comment: If you have `--name`, it's `--name container-name image-name:tag`.  Your command line is missing the `container-name`; or the proposed alternative omits `--name container-name` altogether.